# How remove camera preview to raspberry pi

Tags: python, linux, opencv, raspberry-pi, simplecv

I installed the SimpleCv on my raspberryPi and the driver to use the camera board with it (uv4l driver) and now I'd like to play with it. 
When I type on simpleCV shell "Camera(0).getImage().save("foo.jpg") " , on the screen appears the camera preview and I am not able to type other command because this preview covers the shell
What Have I to do to remove the camera preview ? 
Thanks a lot !
Filippo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the nopreview option

`pkill uv4l`
`uv4l --driver raspicam --auto-video_nr --encoding yuv420 --width 320 --height 240 --nopreview`
`export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/uv4l/uv4lext/armv6l/libuv4lext.so`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The RasPi camera is more integrated than a standard plug-play webcamera, and as a result, I haven't had much sucess using simpleCV's camera functions. Instead I use a simple python script that I call prior to running my simpleCV analysis that grabs an image and saves it to the disk

```
import subprocess

imgName = '/home/pi/blahblah.jpg'

def takePicture(imgName):
    subprocess.call('raspistill -n -t 1 -o %s' &imgName, shell = True)
```