# Setting up SimpleCV with uv4l raspicam driver

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, simplecv

I have installed uv4l raspicam driver (driver for the rasberryPi's camera CSI camera module) from [here](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14). After installation I have followed [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891900/how-remove-camera-preview-to-raspberry-pi) to remove the video preview when I use SimpleCV and to set up 640x480 as resolution. It works, but now I have some problems to set up the camera properties like width and height in SimpleCV. When I run:

```
from SimpleCV import *
c = Camera()
im = c.getImage()

im.show()
```

it runs as a 64x64 window instead of 640x480. So, [here](http://help.simplecv.org/question/41/how-can-i-set-the-camera-capture-width-and-height/) the user fixed this problem, but when I change my code with:

```
from SimpleCV import *
    c = Camera(prop_set={"width":640,"height":480})
    im = c.getImage()

    im.show()
```

it returns me an error:

`[0]`
`WARNING: caught exception: SystemError('/dev/video0 does not support streaming i/o',)`
`WARNING: SimpleCV can't seem to find a camera on your system, or the drivers do not work with SimpleCV.`

`Traceback (most recent call last):`
  `File "/home/pi/Desktop/sorgenti/Simple_CV_acq.py", line 17, in <module>`
   `im = c.getImage()`
  `File "/home/pi/Code/SimpleCV/SimpleCV/Camera.py", line 618, in getImage`
    `cv.GrabFrame(self.capture)`
`TypeError: Expected CvCapture for argument 'capture'`

How can I set properties of the cam in SimpleCV ?

Comment: Hi, I do have the same problem right now. Did you find a solution? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the environment variable.

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/uv4l/uv4lext/armv6l/libuv4lext.so
```